# How does Selenium PageFactory.InitElements Work

Tags: c#, selenium, page-factory

I am using Selenium Page factory and I want to make certain extensions to it, but can't as they are sealed, so I want to write my own custom logic.

Question : 
How does PageFactory.InitElements work so that all the properties loads their values when they are getting used and not when this method is called..

So, To Explain it with an example

```
    //// Button on page load 
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#lst-ib")]
    public IWebElement Btn;

    //// Button redirecting to Page 2
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#lst-ib")]
    public IWebElement LinkBtn;

    ////Button on second page
    [FindsBy(How=How.CssSelector, Using = "#rso > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > h3 > a")]
    public IWebElement NewBtn;
```

So, the beauty of their page factory is that all the elements are loaded but they convert to webelements when they are in use, beacause if all the properties are assigned values on initilisation, NewBtn Property would always fail, as it is on page 2 .

So, what concept they might be using of initializing properties so they are assigned on usage and not at the run time , any dummy code would be great and appreciated to understand

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I have got absolutely no experience in C# but I checked the source code of the C# selenium implementation and seems pretty much identical to the Java code.

[PageFactory.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects/PageFactory.cs) - This class provides the overall framework of how the elements are initialized. 
The `initElements()` gets all the fields in the `pageobject`. For each field gets the annotation on them. Then it creates a `Proxy` for each field. 
Then it stores the actual locator to be used. The actual call to `findElement or findElements` is inside the `Invoke` method of the proxy.

This is all handled by two classes - [DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects/DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.cs) and [DefaultElementLocator.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects/DefaultElementLocator.cs). There are two proxies which handle invocations - [WebElementProxy.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects/WebElementProxy.cs) and [WebElementListProxy.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/PageObjects/WebElementListProxy.cs)

So the **custom logic** that you want to write could be done by creating new classes which implement the appropriate interfaces. Then pass these new classes into the appropriate `initElement()` method of [PageFactory](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_PageFactory.htm) class.

For a detailed understanding look at the `Decorate()` method of `DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.cs` class.

Comment: It's refreshing to see a question/answer about the actual implementation of selenium itself, rather than asking specific questions about code implementation. Your answer is very interesting, thank you for posting it. I did see a bit of selenium source code (I needed to understand the Wait functions and resolve some problems on some weird exceptions I got), but never got to element initialization. Thank you for your explanation. Saved me quite some time for when I get there to see how elements work. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the page object, the "page object logic" (*IMO, from my experience and what I have understood so far from c# and selenium*) it expects all the elements mentioned in an element map to exist in the DOM.

If your NewBtn exists in the dome but is hidden (and becomes visible when navigating to second page, basically when the page does not get refreshed and there is some ajax to it), then it stands to reason that the element map won't have any problem handling the element. You just have to assure that the element is visible with an IF statement or add a wait (to see if you are indeed to the second page).

If the page gets refreshed when navigating to the second page, then simply re-initialize your page object with `new MyPageObject()` so that all elements get mapped again, to avoid StaleElement and/or ElementNotFound exceptions etc.